# Four column forms layout with css

Tags: html, css, forms

I have achieved nice a two column layout form with the help of CSS wiht the help of the following guide.

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/fancy-form-design-css

My markup looks roughly like

```
<form>
  <fieldset> 
    <legend>
      <ol>
        <li>
           <label>
           </label>
           <field>
           <field>
        </li>
        <!-- more fileds -->
      </ol>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
     <!-- similar -->
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

This creates a nice two column layout. What I would like to achieve is that instad of placing the fieldsets one after the other vertically, place them side by side. This should give me a four column layout.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your CSS:**

```
fieldset { display: inline; }
```

The `<fieldset>` element is a `block`-type by default. Changing it to `inline` will make them sit next to each other.

You can also achieve this effect with `float: left;` but that may cause other layout issues.

Comment: Thanks, this sort of worked, but now the alignment looks very strage.  Here the link to how the form looks:   http://picasaweb.google.com/109557476227180026809/Shots#5535243967626674674                                                                     Here the css   http://pastebin.com/2pY7YCgZ                               and form       http://pastebin.com/mqBgY4PZ                                How can this be fixed ?

Comment: I fixed it with adding { vertical-align: top; }.